# Java: How to parse a structured TXT file?

Tags: java

I am trying to create a converter from a structured TXT into Excel table and I am having issues with TXT file reading and proper data storing.

A TXT file is given with the following content:

> -
>  HOSTNAME: hostname1
>  IP: ipAddress1
>  DEVICE INFO:
>  NAME: deviceName1_1, SERIALNUMBER: serialNumber1_1
>   -
>  HOSTNAME: hostname2
>  IP: ipAddress2
>  DEVICE INFO:
>  NAME: deviceName2_1, SERIALNUMBER: serialNumber2_1
>  NAME: deviceName2_2,
>   SERIALNUMBER: serialNumber2_2
>  NAME: deviceName2_3, SERIALNUMBER:
>   serialNumber2_3
>   -
>  HOSTNAME: hostname3
>  IP: ipAddress3
>  DEVICE INFO:
>  NAME: deviceName3_1, SERIALNUMBER: serialNumber3_1
>  NAME: deviceName3_2,
>   SERIALNUMBER: serialNumber3_2

Please take notice that this TXT file has 3 *blocks of information*. Each *block of information* is split by a special symbol "-". A TXT file can have more or less *blocks of information*. Under *device info* there can be more or less lines of *device names* and *serial numbers*.

It is expected to parse the file and to store data in created objects.

An object should have these fields:

```
String hostname;
String ip;
String name;
String serialnumber;
```

Usually 1 object may be created per *block of information*. If under the *device info* there are multiple lines of *device name* and *serial number*, then multiple objects should be created having the same *hostname* and *IP*, but different *device name* and *serial number*.

The expected result:
In total 6 objects should be created with the following data.

> Object#1 has hostname1, ipAddress1, deviceName1, serialNumber1
>   Object#2 has hostname2, ipAddress2, deviceName2_1, serialNumber2_1
>  Object#3 has hostname2, ipAddress2, deviceName2_2, serialNumber2_2
>  Object#4 has hostname2, ipAddress2,
>   deviceName2_3, serialNumber2_3
>  Object#5 has
>   hostname3, ipAddress3, deviceName3_1, serialNumber3_1
>  Object#6 has hostname3, ipAddress3, deviceName3_2, serialNumber3_2

So far I have tried writing this code:

```
private ArrayList<Device> readFile() {

        ArrayList<Device> devices = new ArrayList<Device>
        BufferedReader br = null;

            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(txtFile)));

                String line = "";
                String data;
                int i=0;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
//                  Device device = new Device();
                    if (line.equals("-")) {
//                      Device device = new Device();
                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            Device device = new Device();
                            if (line.contains("HOSTNAME: ")) {
//                              Device device = new Device();
                                if (line.substring(0,10).equals("HOSTNAME: ")) {
                                    device.setHostname(line.substring(10,line.length()));
                                    devices.add(device);
                                }
                            }
                            if (line.contains("IP: ")) {
//                              Device device = new Device();
                                if (line.substring(0,4).equals("IP: ")) {
                                    device.setIp(line.substring(4,line.length()));
                                    devices.add(device);
                                }
                            }
                        devices.add(device);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

But then objects have a hostname, but IP is NULL or vice versa. I have also tried this code:

```
try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(txtFile);
            int i = 0;
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                String array[] = line.split(",");
                DeviceData device = new DeviceData(array[0],array[1]);
                System.out.println("Eilute " + (i++) + ": " + array[0]);
    }
```

But I have lost myself here.

I am having trouble with separating desired data and putting it into objects. How should I do it right as expected? Any ideas and/or suggestions?

Comment: You could add a check for the - symbol, and then just loop, and check for the next line until you've reached the end of the document.

Comment: @SvenOlderaan Yes, I have added a check for the symbol " - ", it is shown in my code fragment
_if (line.equals("-")) {_

and I have tried making another loop with while. But it still gives me line by line, and I can't put the data in each object for each loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create device objects when you encounter a line starting with "NAME: ". In order to keep the IP and HOSTNAME values, you should use local variables. A sample implementation could look like this:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream(txtFile)));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.equals("-")) {
        String ip = null;
        String hostname = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains("HOSTNAME: ")) {
                if (line.substring(0, 10).equals("HOSTNAME: ")) {
                    hostname = line.substring(10, line.length());
                }
            }

            if (line.contains("IP: ")) {
                if (line.substring(0, 4).equals("IP: ")) {
                    ip = line.substring(4, line.length());
                }
            }

            if (line.contains("NAME: ")) {
                if (line.substring(0, 6).equals("NAME: ")) {
                    Device device = new Device();
                    device.setIp(ip);
                    device.setHostname(hostname);
                    System.out.println("Adding device with ip = " +
                            ip + " and hostname " + hostname);
                    System.out.println("Details: " + line);
                    devices.add(device);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tested it and it works!
It was needed to define _ip_ and _hostname_ fields under the first while loop and name field should be defined under the second while loop. The object had to be created when line with "NAME:" is found, really!
It so makes sense now. Thank you!

Comment: @ig90 Glad this answer worked for you. While this answer is correct, keep in mind that it is always a good idea to check your file, to see if it has the right structure. See my answer on how to do that properly. Its standalone and ready to run (except the Device class).

Answer (score 0):

I would structure the parsing into multiple functions and also check, if the syntax of the file is right. Suggestion:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ReadDevices {

    public static class InvalidFileException extends Exception {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -6525977749423883875L;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Device> devices;
        try {
            devices = readFile("yourFile.txt");
        } catch (IOException | InvalidFileException e) {
            System.out.println("Something is wrong with the file!");
            return;
        }
        // do something with devices
    }

    public static ArrayList<Device> readFile(String file) throws IOException, InvalidFileException {
        ArrayList<Device> devices = new ArrayList<Device>();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));

        // discard "-"
        assertLine(reader.readLine(), "-");
        String hostnameLine;
        while ((hostnameLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String hostname = parseLineWithLabel(hostnameLine, "HOSTNAME");
            String ip = parseLineWithLabel(reader.readLine(), "IP");
            assertLine(reader.readLine(), "DEVICE INFO:");

            String line;
            String[] deviceLabels = new String[] { "NAME", "SERIALNUMBER" };
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.equals("-"))
                    break;
                String[] deviceInfo = parseLineWithMultiLabel(line, deviceLabels);
                devices.add(new Device(hostname, ip, deviceInfo[0], deviceInfo[1]));
            }
        }
        reader.close();
        return devices;
    }

    private static String parseLineWithLabel(String line, String label) throws InvalidFileException {
        String[] parts = line.split(": ");
        if (!parts[0].equals(label))
            throw new InvalidFileException();
        return parts[1];
    }

    private static String[] parseLineWithMultiLabel(String line, String[] labels) throws InvalidFileException {
        String[] multi = line.split(", ");
        String[] result = new String[multi.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < multi.length; i++)
            result[i] = parseLineWithLabel(multi[i], labels[i]);
        return result;
    }

    private static void assertLine(String line, String value) throws InvalidFileException {
        if (!line.equals(value))
            throw new InvalidFileException();
    }
}
```

It will throw an InvalidFileException if the file has not the right structure. You can then handle the error in the calling function.

Comment: I looked carefully at your code. It is compact, advanced and useful.
I tried using it but at 
_assertLine(reader.readLine(), "DEVICE INFO:");_
it doesn't compare the String _line_ and String _value_ well:
**NAME: deviceName1_1, SERIALNUMBER: serialNumber1_1** and **DEVICE INFO:**

Still, your code is interesting, I will have to explore it more. Thank you for sharing this code.

Comment: @ig90 Hmm that is weired. I actually tried my code with your sample data, and it works flawlessly. Maybe your file structure is a little off? Like leading or trailing whitespaces? By the way, it would be clever to trim those away while processing ;)

Comment: Aha! Because I added some System.out.printlns above your _assertLine(reader.readLine(), "DEVICE INFO:");_ it threw me an exception. When adding additional print lines, the _assertLine_ method doesn't catch appropriate lines to check. That's interesting. 

Without my print lines, your code works flawlessly indeed.

And yes, I will trim whitespaces programmatically :)